# Should Bullet physics be refactored to be used in a DirectX application?

Tags: refactoring, directx, physics, bulletphysics, particle-system

I've played around with some of the examples and they look real good.

However I noticed Bullet uses its own vector structs and math utilities. I'm using DirectXMath for the rest of the DirectX application. So this means I have two sets of math functions.

I believe the DirectXMath one to be the more efficient one, but Bullet is 130,000 lines long, so I have to be sure before I start refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

There's pretty much no need to refactor.

That sounds a daunting task specially considering the amount of errors that can be potentially introduced in the process (and bullet math is pretty fast also, with the advantage of being inlined over a call on d3d functions).

Just use bullet datatypes for the simulation and convert them into d3d math datatypes when needed (since they have same memory layout a pointer cast will do the job and has pretty much zero cost, with a few c++ casting operators it will also make the process almost transparent)